# foreach loop where to put $u++

Tags: javascript, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I really need your help, if someone can help me thank you very much,
I am new in programming, and I have this code, I do not know where to put `$u++;` so that u can increase for 1, everytime, I am a little bit confused because its javascript mixed with laravel this is my code:

```
<?php $u=0;  ?>;

var dropdown = [('
  <select  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="drop_down_owner" value=0  id="dropdown_id">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
        @if($answer->drop_down_owner==$u)
        <option  name ="answer_id" value="answer_id[]">
          {{$answer->text}}
        </option>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </select>
')];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Could you just use the [loop variable `$loop->index`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable)

Comment: I read "thank you but this does not work, because it is inside javascript, it shows undefined but thanks anyway" from you comments. Please make this reflect in your questions and tags!

Comment: U need to pass it as a js variable and if you are using this inside blade use @var before variable.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, is this code in a `.blade.php` file or a `js` file?

Comment: laravel 5.4, and it is .blade.php

Comment: this way works but its static var dropdown = [('<select.. if answer->drop_down_owner = 0  ' .. </select>), ('<select.. if answer->drop_down_owner = 1  ' .. </select>)') ];

Comment: Could you post all of your code? It's kinda of hard to debug without all of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. You want to increment the value right before the next iteration of the loop.

```
var dropdown = `
  <select  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="drop_down_owner" value=0  id="dropdown_id">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
        @if($answer->drop_down_owner == $loop->index)
        <option  name ="answer_id" value="answer_id[]">
          {{$answer->text}}
        </option>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </select>
`;
```

Comment: thank you but this does not work, because it is inside javascript, it shows undefined but thanks anyway

Comment: What are you trying to do? How about now?

Comment: I need that  @if($answer->drop_down_owner==$u)   the $u  to start like this     @if($answer->drop_down_owner==0) and increase, but that way <?php $u++;?>  does not work, and $loop->index I do not know how to use it, because I need that condition @if($answer->drop_down_owner==$u), thank you for your effort I really apretiate it

Comment: Okay, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
     @php 
         $u=0; 
        @endphp

        var dropdown = [('
          <select  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="drop_down_owner" value=0  id="dropdown_id">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                @if($answer->drop_down_owner==$u)
                <option  name ="answer_id" value="answer_id[]">
                  {{$answer->text}}
                </option>
                @endif
                @php
                 $u++;
                @endphp
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </select>
        ')];
```